# Collapsable mat-sidenav menu rezise content not working

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material, mat-sidenav

I'm making an Angular 9 app and I want to add a sidenav to my project.

The sidenav that I want is exactly like this Primer Angular Template --> [Primer - Angular 8+ Material](https://primer.fusepx.com/angular/)

This is what I want

[image]

And This is what I got with my scss and html. The problem is that the content is not rezising when the sidebar is collapsed, and then, the style is breaking. For this I am looking for an answer with `mat-sidenav-container` and `mat-sidenav`

[image]

**HTML**

```
<mat-sidenav-container  class="app example-sidenav-container" autosize>
  <mat-sidenav #sidenav class="example-sidenav" mode="side" opened="true" [ngStyle]="{ 'width': !collapsedSidebar ? '250px':'70px' }">
    <button mat-icon-button (click)="collapsedSidebar = !collapsedSidebar">
      <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
   </button>
  </mat-sidenav>

  <div fxFlex  class="example-sidenav-content">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

**SCSS**

```
.app { height: 100vh; }
.example-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.example-sidenav-container { flex: 1; }
.example-sidenav{
  -webkit-transition: width .4s;
  transition: width .4s;
}
.mat-drawer{ background:White; }
.example-sidenav-content {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #e8ded7;
  opacity: 0.9;
}
.example-fill-remaining-space { flex: 1 1 auto; }
```

Please help

**UPDATE**
Here is a Stackblitz example --> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xa3n5i

Comment: can you add a stackblits exemple

Comment: @AymenTAGHLISSIA I just added the stackblitz example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xa3n5i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved a similar problem in one of my apps before. I used `ngClass` and a boolean controlling both `mat-sidenav` width property and `mat-sidenav-content` `margin-left` property . Here is a stackblitz, i sliced out relevant part from that app.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mff93r

Comment: Thank you very much, that's exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

I'm suggesting that the bar with the icons is located outside the sidenav but with the menu items and its relevant icon is aligned.

You can then use the native functionality to toggle the sidenav visiblity.

```
<div class="app">
    <button mat-icon-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()">
        <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
   </button>
    <div style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: 48px auto;height: 100%;">
        <div class="icons">
            <div class="icon">Icon</div>
            <div class="icon">Icon</div>
        </div>
        <mat-sidenav-container autosize>
            <mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" opened="true">
                <div class="item">Item 1 text</div>
                <div class="item">Item 2 text</div>
            </mat-sidenav>

            <div fxFlex class="example-sidenav-content">
                a verss
            </div>
        </mat-sidenav-container>
    </div>
<div>
```

See stackblitz example: https://angular-cymk69.stackblitz.io

Comment: Thank you, It would be an effective solution, unfortunately it does not adapt when the screen is small, also, I have a menu with modules and sub-modules in accordion mode that would be affected if the icons are in a separate div

Comment: I see your point, although that could be solved using directives for aligning the icons to their item.

Answer (score 0):

Your app-component.html

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="app-container">

  <mat-sidenav #sidenav             
              [mode]="mode"
              [opened]="opened">

    <button (click)="toggleSideNav()">toggle</button>

  </mat-sidenav>

  <router-outlet class="container"></router-outlet>

</mat-sidenav-container>
```

Your app-component.scss

```
.app-sidenav {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Your app-component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {MediaChange, MediaObserver} from "@angular/flex-layout";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  mode: string;
  opened = true;

  constructor(private mediaObserver: MediaObserver) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.mediaObserver.asObservable().subscribe((change: MediaChange[]) => {

      const isMobileView = change[0].mqAlias === 'xs' || change[0].mqAlias === 'sm';
      this.mode = isMobileView ? 'over' : 'side';

    });

    // track auth state, something like this.
    // this.opened = hasLoggedIn && (!isMobileView);

  }

  // other code.


}
```